Stub not able to connect Temporal server
I am trying to submit Temporal workflow using a springboot application, and i am using docker compose.
Creating the stub using below code
WorkflowServiceStubsOptions workflowServiceStubsOptions = WorkflowServiceStubsOptions.newBuilder()
            .setTarget(temporalServerUrl).build();
WorkflowServiceStubs.newServiceStubs(workflowServiceStubsOptions);

'temporalServerUrl' is the property passing to the docker file as property name as 'temporal.server.url'
Below is the snippet of compose file
version: "3.5"
services:
  temporal:
    container_name: temporal
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    environment:
      - DB=postgresql
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_USER=temporal
      - POSTGRES_PWD=temporal
      - POSTGRES_SEEDS=postgresql
      - DYNAMIC_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config/dynamicconfig/development-sql.yaml
    image: temporalio/auto-setup:${TEMPORAL_VERSION}
    networks:
      - temporal-network
    ports:
      - 7233:7233
    volumes:
      - ./dynamicconfig:/etc/temporal/config/dynamicconfig
    labels:
      kompose.volume.type: configMap
  temporal-ps-wf-submit:
    container_name: temporal-ps-wf-submit
    depends_on:
      - temporal
    environment:
      - TEMPORAL_ADDRESS=temporal:7233
      - TEMPORAL_CORS_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000
      - temporal.server.url=temporal:7233
    image: postgres-workflow-client:1.0.0
    networks:
      - temporal-network
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

When run the compose file, it is showing below error.
2024-04-28T07:06:15.338Z  WARN 1 --- [ault-executor-0] io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl      : [Channel<1>: (temporal:7233)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host temporal, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: temporal: Name or service not known
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: temporal: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(Unknown Source)

Any clue?
Thanks in Adv

Have you found a solution yet?

Looks to me like this really is about Docker+Java, rather than Temporal-specific. Can you check at the /etc/resolv.conf file in your temporal-ps-wf-submit container?

What if you open a shell in that container, and from there, try to use any command that you have access to that prints out the IP of some hostname (e.g. ping, nslookup, dig…)? If resolving the address using such a command doesn't work, then for sure, it work in Java either.
